# Consuming Azure hosted WebApi in MS Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

We are using MS Dynamics Crm 2016 Online, we are required to consume Azure Hosted WebApi from client side. We are trying to get data using ajax call.. the same code works for us outside MS Dynamics Crm but within Dynamics Crm we are getting Access denied error. We have enabled CORS in the webapi but we still experince this issue. It looks like it is something related to Dynamics CRM but we are not able to find the cause and solution.

Below is the sample code which **works outside MS Dynamics CRM**

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://myaccountapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Account',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'testaccount',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                processData(data);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.statusText);
            }
        });
```

But this same code throws error **within** CRM which says : **Access denied**.

Comment: did you add any defense layers or authentication layers to the API?

Comment: from the code you posted it's hard to find the cause

Comment: API is open at the moment ... no Authentication is required.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a page from `orgName.crmX.dynamics.com` trying to call to `myaccountapi.azurewebsites.net`. This is not a CRM issue.

You are making a cross-site request that is likely resulting in an access denied message - since, I'm guessing, you have not enabled CORS in the WebApi application.

You can review the full example at: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api.

> Enable CORS
>
> Now let's enable CORS in the WebService app. First, add the CORS NuGet
>   package. In Visual Studio, from the Tools menu, select Library Package
>   Manager, then select Package Manager Console. In the Package Manager
>   Console window, type the following command:
>
> `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`
>
> This command installs the latest package and updates all dependencies,
>   including the core Web API libraries. User the -Version flag to target
>   a specific version. The CORS package requires Web API 2.0 or later.
>
> Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the
>   WebApiConfig.Register method.
>
> ```
> using System.Web.Http;
> namespace WebService
> {
>     public static class WebApiConfig
>     {
>         public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
>         {
>             // New code
>             config.EnableCors();
>
>             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
>                 name: "DefaultApi",
>                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
>                 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
>             );
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Next, add the [EnableCors] attribute to the TestController class:
>
> ```
> using System.Net.Http;
> using System.Web.Http;
> using System.Web.Http.Cors;
>
> namespace WebService.Controllers
> {
>     [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
>     public class TestController : ApiController
>     {
>         // Controller methods not shown...
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: the CORS has been enabled but still we are experiencing this issue. I found somewhere on internet that we need to use Azure Service Bus to get data from Azure Hosted API and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As CRM Online is accessed on an encrypted connection you also need to access external resources using SSL. Just change your url to use https and you should be good to go:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'https://myaccountapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Account',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'testaccount',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            processData(data);

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
```