# Get data from Azure hosted SQL server from with in MS Dynamics CRM Sandbox plugin

Tags: sql-server, rest, azure, dynamics-crm

I am stuck in accessing the SQL Server from within Sandbox plugin. As we can't access it from within Sandbox plugin so i tried to access it through azure hosted WebApi but I am unable to access that API from within MS Dynamics CRM through JavaScript as well as through a Plugin, i have reported that issue here:

[Consuming Azure hosted WebApi in MS Dynamics CRM Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200816/consuming-azure-hosted-webapi-in-ms-dynamics-crm-online)

The other thing i tried that i created an azure hosted cloud service but i am unable to access that service from within sandbox plugin. It says 'no endpoint listening that could accept the message', although i have confirmed that azure hosted cloud service is working fine and that the end point is also correct.

So now I am not sure that what setting is am missing in Azure/MS Dynamics CRM. Kindly suggest that what will be the best approach to use in this scenario?

Comment: As I just commented on the question you have linked to above, you probably need to change your code to access your resources on an encrypted connection.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-call-External-WCF-42c4490d

Also from the CRM SDK.

Web access

Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. This capability provides support for accessing popular web resources like social sites, news feeds, web services, and more. The following web access restrictions apply to this sandbox capability.

- Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
- Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
- IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
- Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or
  saving those credentials.